# Passing parent object into CreateView for a child object

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I'm creating a dashboard to edit a tour app.

Per tour I have a child record in which I define steps. The 2 models look like this:

**models.py**

```
class Tour(models.Model):
    tour_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,unique=True, max_length=10)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Countries, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='country')
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='language')
    lastupddtm = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    productid = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descrlong = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    live = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_tour_image, storage=OverwriteStorage(), blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tour'
        verbose_name_plural = "tour"


    def get_language_flag(self):
        return self.language.flag.url

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.tour_id) + ' - ' + str(self.title) + ' - ' + str(self.description)



class Toursteps(models.Model):
    # tour_id = models.OneToOneField(Tour, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='tour_id')
    tour = models.ForeignKey(Tour, related_name='toursteps', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    step = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descrlong = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    audiotext = models.TextField()
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
    radius = models.FloatField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_tour_step_image, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tourSteps'
        verbose_name_plural = "tourSteps"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.tour) + "|" + str(self.step)
```

After I created a Tour, I go to a detail page. From there I can click a link to add a step for this tour.
This is where the problem is. I pass the tour_id as a variable into the url, but I can't find a way to pick it up in the CreateView of the step.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('tour/<str:pk>/detail', views.TourDetailView.as_view(), name='tour_detail'),
    path('tour/<str:pk>/edit', views.UpdateTourView.as_view(), name='tour_edit'),
    path('tour/<str:pk>/remove', views.DeleteTourView.as_view(), name='tour_remove'),
    path('tour/<str:tour_id>/step/new', views.CreateTourStepView.as_view(), name='tour_step_new')
]
```

**Tour detail view**

```
 <p><a href="{% url 'tour_step_new' tour_id=tour.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></p>
```

**views.py**

```
class CreateTourStepView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'tour_admin/tour_list.html'
    success_url = '/'
    form_class = TourStepForm
    model = Toursteps

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateTourStepView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        print(context['tour_id'])
        return context
```

**forms.py**

```
class TourStepForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = Toursteps
        #fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('tour',)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.tour_id = self.request.GET("tour_id")

            form.instance.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('tour_detail', kwargs={'pk':form.instance.tour_id})
```

Comment: Since the `tour_id` is part of your url pattern, it's in the `kwargs` of your view (`self.kwargs`), not in `request.GET` (those are the query parameters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `form_valid()` and `get_success_url()` methods belong in your view, not in your form.

Second, the `tour_id` is passed to the view's `kwargs`, it's not a query parameter, hence not in `self.request.GET`. You can find it in `self.kwargs`.

Third, you need to actually **fetch the `Tour`** from your database, not just assign the `tour_id`. I could post to any `tour_id` if I wanted and there's no guarantee the `tour_id` belongs to an actual `Tour` object. Return a 404 if the tour doesn't exist. And if it exists, assign it to the tour step.

Finally, you should not assign to and save `form.instance`. You should get the instance using `step = form.save(commit=False)`, then assign to `step` and save `step`.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot. self.kwargs was the answer, and I could basically remove the rest of the code you mentioned. there was no need to fetch the tour_id, as the check was already done on database level via the Foreign Key contruction.

Comment: The check is done but it throws a database integrity error when saving which is not a really nice user experience (also because in your logs is raises an error when actually nothing is really wrong except user input). Returning a 404 is a better experience.